# Grainy textures in a simple cube scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm just starting to learn three.js and have been trying to set up a simple textured cube box in an isometric view. When I add edge lines to my cube it turns out to be quite grainy on a few of the edges.

I've tried moving the camera and aspect ratio a bit but to no avail.

```js
var aspect = 100/100
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var d = 100;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - d * aspect, d * aspect, d, - d, 1, 500 );
camera.position.set( 80, 80, 80 ); // all components equal
camera.lookAt( scene.position ); // or the origin

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: true });
renderer.setSize( 100, 80 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 65, 65, 65 );
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry )
var line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000} ) );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xf0f0f5 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );
scene.add( line );


var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.min.js"></script>
```

The above gives me a nice grey cube with black edges but the edges appear grainy in my browser.

Picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: Did you try with antialiasing enabled? `var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: true, antialias: true });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) issue, which can be solved by a polgon offset [`.polygonOffset`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material).
The issue is caused because the lines and the surface have to same coordinates and depth.

Set the [`.polygonOffset`, `.polygonOffsetFactor` and `.polygonOffsetUnits`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material) property of that [`THREE.Material`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material), which is set to the solid geometry.
This causes that the surfaces are slightly pushed to the back and the lines cover the surfaces:

e.g.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    color: 0xf0f0f5,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: 1.0,
    polygonOffsetUnits: -4.0 
} );
```

[image]

```js
var aspect = 100/100
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var d = 100;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - d * aspect, d * aspect, d, - d, 1, 500 );
camera.position.set( 80, 80, 80 ); // all components equal
camera.lookAt( scene.position ); // or the origin

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: true });
renderer.setSize( 100, 80 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 65, 65, 65 );
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry )
var line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000} ) );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    color: 0xf0f0f5,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: 1.0,
    polygonOffsetUnits: -4.0 
} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( line );
scene.add( cube );

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.min.js"></script>
```